# logout in capybara with bootstrap menu

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, bootstrap-4, capybara

I'm having trouble testing menus in bootstrap 4 over capybara.

The navigation menu snippet looks like this:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" >
      <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="userDropdown">
        User
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
        <%= link_to 'logout', logout_url, method: :post, class: 'dropdown-item'%>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In debug mode, this almost works:

```rb
find('#userDropdown').execute_script('$(this).dropdown("toggle")')
click_on 'logout'
```

"Almost" because in byebug, the browser looks always one step behind. Triggering any kind of action, e.g. selecting something it does not exists, moves it forward to the expected state.

From there, those actions work.

But in the test I get a `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` on the `click_on 'logout'` line.

Workaround (works now):

```
find('#userDropdown', visible: false).execute_script('$(this).dropdown("toggle")')
click_on 'logout'
```

Is almost the same as before. I was missing the visibility attribute and the error was just misleading. But too much hard-coded...

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're attempting to use `execute_script` to open the menu rather than just interacting with it as a user would?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I couldn't find a better way... `.hover` didn't work and I do not know of other options.

Comment: Well what does a user have to do to make the menu visible -- if  `#userDropdown` requires `visible: false` to find then it means it's not visible on the page - which means there's a different element the user has to hover over or click on to make the menu visible, and that's what you should be doing

Answer (score 0):

Apologies as I can't comment to receive clarity so I have to post this as an answer.

Three things that I'd look into further here:

1. Does `find('#userDropdown').click` work? If so, try that as it's more natural from a user's perspective and may lead to a more accurate 'failure'.
2. Is the entire nav hidden due to the window size in the test browser?
3. Not that it's best practice at all but without touching the dropdown at all can you do `find(:xpath, "//a[text()='logout']", visible: false).click`? You could even temporarily add a CSS id and use that rather than faff about with xpath.

Of these three I expect the third is the most likely to work but also the least likely to identify the issue and not good practice. Hope this helps.

Comment: 1) no, it does not (the link is within the menu and hidden) 2) no, the size is ok, the menu bar can be seen 3) I did something like this, but as you said... is not good...

Comment: Given 1) and 2), can you take the necessary steps to make the link visible? Do you need to hover over something or click on something?